# Railsでjoinsを使用しても片方のテーブルからしか値を取得できない原因は何でしょうか？

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord

### 実現したいこと

Railsで下記のようなクエリを実行し、shopsとareasの値を取得したいです。

```sql
SELECT shops.*, areas.*
FROM shops
LEFT OUTER JOIN areas
ON shop.id = areas.id
```

下記のような結果を取得したいです。

```sql
<Shop id: 1, shop_name: "est店", created_at: "2021-05-17 01:45:34", updated_at: "2021-05-17 01:45:34", shop_type_id: 1, station_id: 1, area_id: 1, prefectures: "nisi県", municipalities: "officiis市", house_number: nil, building_name: nil, postal_code: nil, created_at: "2021-05-27 07:49:13", updated_at: "2021-05-27 07:49:13">
```

### 関連付けは下記のようになっています。

```rb
models % cat shop.rb 
class Shop < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :shop_type
    belongs_to :area
    belongs_to :station
end

models % cat area.rb
class Area < ApplicationRecord
    has_one :shop
end
```

### マイグレーションは下記のようになっています。

```rb
migrate % cat 20210511064507_create_shops.rb
class CreateShops < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.0]
  def change
    create_table :shops do |t|
      t.string :name

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end

migrate % cat 20210513091441_create_areas.rb
class CreateAreas < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.0]
  def change
    create_table :areas do |t|
      t.string :prefectures
      t.string :municipalities
      t.string :house_number
      t.string :building_name
      t.integer :postal_code

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end

migrate % cat 20210514012107_add_foreign_key_to_shop.rb
class AddForeignKeyToShop < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.0]
  def change
    add_column :shops, :shop_type_id, :integer
    add_column :shops, :station_id, :integer
    add_column :shops, :area_id, :integer
    
    add_foreign_key :shops, :shop_types
    add_foreign_key :shops, :stations
    add_foreign_key :shops, :areas
  end
end
```

### 起こっている問題

Railsで`joins`を使用しselectに`shops.*, areas.*`を指定していますがshopsの値のみ取得されareasが取得できません。

```rb
irb(main):172:0> Shop.first
  Shop Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "shops".* FROM "shops" ORDER BY "shops"."id" ASC LIMIT ?  [["LIMIT", 1]]
=> #<Shop id: 1, shop_name: "est店", created_at: "2021-05-17 01:45:34", updated_at: "2021-05-17 01:45:34", shop_type_id: 1, station_id: 1, area_id: 1>

irb(main):174:0> Area.first
  Area Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "areas".* FROM "areas" ORDER BY "areas"."id" ASC LIMIT ?  [["LIMIT", 1]]
=> #<Area id: 1, prefectures: "eum県", municipalities: "ut市", house_number: nil, building_name: nil, postal_code: nil, created_at: "2021-05-17 01:45:34", updated_at: "2021-05-17 01:45:34">

irb(main):177:0> Shop.joins(:area).select("shops.*, areas.*").first
  Shop Load (0.2ms)  SELECT shops.*, areas.* FROM "shops" INNER JOIN "areas" ON "areas"."id" = "shops"."area_id" ORDER BY "shops"."id" ASC LIMIT ?  [["LIMIT", 1]]
=> #<Shop id: 1, shop_name: "est店", created_at: "2021-05-17 01:45:34", updated_at: "2021-05-17 01:45:34", shop_type_id: 1, station_id: 1, area_id: 1>
```

---

### 2021/05/27追記

`eager_load`を使うことで期待していた`LEFT OUTER JOIN`を実行できました。

ですが下記のようにshopsのカラムを取得できるのですがareasのカラムは取得できませんでした。

```sql
Shop.eager_load(:area).first
  SQL (0.1ms)  SELECT "shops"."id" AS t0_r0, "shops"."shop_name" AS t0_r1, "shops"."created_at" AS t0_r2, "shops"."updated_at" AS t0_r3, "shops"."shop_type_id" AS t0_r4, "shops"."station_id" AS t0_r5, "shops"."area_id" AS t0_r6, "areas"."id" AS t1_r0, "areas"."prefectures" AS t1_r1, "areas"."municipalities" AS t1_r2, "areas"."house_number" AS t1_r3, "areas"."building_name" AS t1_r4, "areas"."postal_code" AS t1_r5, "areas"."created_at" AS t1_r6, "areas"."updated_at" AS t1_r7 FROM "shops" LEFT OUTER JOIN "areas" ON "areas"."id" = "shops"."area_id" ORDER BY "shops"."id" ASC LIMIT ?  [["LIMIT", 1]]
=> #<Shop id: 1, shop_name: "facere店", created_at: "2021-05-27 07:49:13", updated_at: "2021-05-27 07:49:13", shop_type_id: 1, station_id: 1, area_id: 1>
```

実行されているSQLをみるとSELECT句にareasのカラムである`"areas"."prefectures"`　などが指定されていますが、返された値にはshopsのカラムしかなく、何が原因でしょうか？

### 2021/05/28追記

ご回答いただいた下記の手順ではエラーになってしまいました。

```sql
irb(main):001:0> shop = Shop.eager_load(:area)
   (0.4ms)  SELECT sqlite_version(*)
  SQL (0.1ms)  SELECT "shops"."id" AS t0_r0, "shops"."shop_name" AS t0_r1, "shops"."created_at" AS t0_r2, "shops"."updated_at" AS t0_r3, "shops"."shop_type_id" AS t0_r4, "shops"."station_id" AS t0_r5, "shops"."area_id" AS t0_r6, "areas"."id" AS t1_r0, "areas"."prefectures" AS t1_r1, "areas"."municipalities" AS t1_r2, "areas"."house_number" AS t1_r3, "areas"."building_name" AS t1_r4, "areas"."postal_code" AS t1_r5, "areas"."created_at" AS t1_r6, "areas"."updated_at" AS t1_r7 FROM "shops" LEFT OUTER JOIN "areas" ON "areas"."id" = "shops"."area_id" LIMIT ?  [["LIMIT", 11]]
=> #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Shop id: 1, shop_name: "facere店", created_at: "2021-05-27 07:49:13", updated_at: "2021-05-27 07:49:13", shop_type_id: 1, station_id: 1, area_id: 1>, #<Shop id: 2, shop_name: "facere店", created_at: "2021-05-27 07:49:13", updated_at: "2021-05-27 07:49:13", shop_type_id: 2, station_id: 2, area_id: 2>, #<Shop id: 3, shop_name: "facere店", created_at: "2021-05-27 07:49:13", updated_at: "2021-05-27 07:49:13", shop_type_id: 3, station_id: 3, area_id: 3>, #<Shop id: 4, shop_name: "facere店", created_at: "2021-05-27 07:49:13", updated_at: "2021-05-27 07:49:13", shop_type_id: 4, station_id: 4, area_id: 4>, #<Shop id: 5, shop_name: "facere店", created_at: "2021-05-27 07:49:13", updated_at: "2021-05-27 07:49:13", shop_type_id: 5, station_id: 5, area_id: 5>, #<Shop id: 6, shop_name: "facere店", created_at: "2021-05-27 07:49:13", updated_at: "2021-05-27 07:49:13", shop_type_id: 6, station_id: 6, area_id: 6>, #<Shop id: 7, shop_name: "facere店", created_at: "2021-05-27 07:49:13", updated_at: "2021-05-27 07:49:13", shop_type_id: 7, station_id: 7, area_id: 7>, #<Shop id: 8, shop_name: "facere店", created_at: "2021-05-27 07:49:13", updated_at: "2021-05-27 07:49:13", shop_type_id: 8, station_id: 8, area_id: 8>, #<Shop id: 9, shop_name: "facere店", created_at: "2021-05-27 07:49:13", updated_at: "2021-05-27 07:49:13", shop_type_id: 9, station_id: 9, area_id: 9>, #<Shop id: 10, shop_name: "facere店", created_at: "2021-05-27 07:49:13", updated_at: "2021-05-27 07:49:13", shop_type_id: 10, station_id: 10, area_id: 10>, ...]>
irb(main):002:0> shop.area
Traceback (most recent call last):
        1: from (irb):2
  SQL (0.2ms)  SELECT "shops"."id" AS t0_r0, "shops"."shop_name" AS t0_r1, "shops"."created_at" AS t0_r2, "shops"."updated_at" AS t0_r3, "shops"."shop_type_id" AS t0_r4, "shops"."station_id" AS t0_r5, "shops"."area_id" AS t0_r6, "areas"."id" AS t1_r0, "areas"."prefectures" AS t1_r1, "areas"."municipalities" AS t1_r2, "areas"."house_number" AS t1_r3, "areas"."building_name" AS t1_r4, "areas"."postal_code" AS t1_r5, "areas"."created_at" AS t1_r6, "areas"."updated_at" AS t1_r7 FROM "shops" LEFT OUTER JOIN "areas" ON "areas"."id" = "shops"."area_id" LIMIT ?  [["LIMIT", 11]]
NoMethodError (undefined method `area' for #<Shop::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x00007fe5fa3c2278>)
Did you mean?  arel
irb(main):003:0>
```

何卒よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: 期待なさっている挙動がいまいち分かりませんでした。どういった挙動を想定されていましたか……？

Comment: 分かりづらく申し訳ありません。

`SELECT shops.*, areas.*
FROM shops
LEFT OUTER JOIN areas
ON shop.id = areas.id
`を実行し、shopsとareasの値を取得したかったです。
質問文では同じようなクエリを`INNER JOIN`で実行できてはいますが、shopsの値しか返されておらず、同時に取得したいareasが取得できていませんでした。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

なさりたいのは `shop = Shop.eager_load(:area)` として `shop.ほにゃらら` を参照したり `shop.area.ほにゃらら` を参照したりといったことでしょうか……？　`joins` だとクエリキャッシュが生まれないので `eager_load` にしていますが、ユースケースによっては `includes` でも良いです。

`Shop.joins(:area).select("shops.*, areas.*").first` だと、計算結果としては `Shop` クラスのインスタンスが返ってくるので、そこには `Area` クラスのインスタンスメソッドは生えていません。また同名カラムの存在を考えるとそういったようにすべきでもありません。

`belongs_to :area` と設定しているため `Shop#area` メソッドによってその `Shop` インスタンスに紐づいた `Area` インスタンスを参照できるので、このメソッドを介してアクセスするようにすると良いです。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。教えていただいた通り`eager_load`を使うことで期待していたLEFT OUTER JOIN　を実行できました。質問文に追記したのですが、shopsのカラムを取得できるのですがareasのカラムは取得できませんでした。

Comment: 回答に書いているとおり、`shop = Shop.eager_load(:area).first` だと返り値は Shop クラスのインスタンスになるので、当然 Area の値は保持していません。Shop クラスがインスタンス変数として持っているのは area_id のみです。ただし `eager_load` を使った場合クエリキャッシュがされているので、`shop.area` を参照するとクエリ無しで Area の値を得ることができます。

Comment: ご回答いただいた`shop = Shop.eager_load(:area)` `shop.area`ですとエラーになってしまいました。(詳細は質問文に追記いたしました)
書き方が良くないでしょうか？
また、情報が後出しになり申し訳ありませんが、「期待している結果」をより具体的に質問文に追記いたしました。
お手数ですが引き続き助言いただけますと幸いです。

Comment: `first` など何かしら条件を指定しないと ActiveRecord のままなのでそのエラーになります。私の例だと `first` を付けているのが違いです。

Comment: shopに関連するareaを`Shop.eager_load(:area).first.area`で取得し問題を解決することができました。ご丁寧にありがとうございました。